# Why doesn't my image load on device, but in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder, uiimageview

I have an ImageView that has a background image that I set in IB. It appears fine in the simulator. When I run the app on my device, the background image doesn't exist. How can I diagnose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is because of case (in)sensitivity in the filesystem. On the simulator, the filesystem is case insensitive. Therefore, it will find files that you refer to even if they HaVe ThEiR CasE MixEd uP. The device filesystem will fail to find the file, however.